# How Can I Make Custom Tabs Using Angular Materials Tabs?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I want to use Angular Material library and build my own library with some custom designs. But facing some problems while splitting the material components. I think the problem is with shadow DOM. Here is the code that i want to achieve.

Code

custom-tabs-group.html -parent

```
<div class="custom-tabs">
  <mat-tab-group disableRipple>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

custom-tabs.html -child

```
<custom-tabs-group [tabContent]="tabContent">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabContent" label="{{tab.title}}">{{tab.content}} </mat-tab>
</custom-tabs-group>
```

is it even possible? Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i figured it out with some hack i don't know if its a good approch or not

custom-tabs.component.html

```
<div class="custom-tabs">
  <mat-tab-group disableRipple>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabsContentList" label="{{tab.label}}">
      <div [innerHTML]="tab.htmlContent"></div>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

custom-tabs-component.ts

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'il-tabs-content',
  template: `
      <div #content>
         <ng-content></ng-content>
       </div>
       `
  ,
})
export class TabsContentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: String;
  @ViewChild('content') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    console.log("block three", content)
    this.htmlContent = content;
    if (this.htmlContent) {
      this.htmlContent = this.htmlContent.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    }
  }

  htmlContent: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'il-tabs-group',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TabsGroupComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(TabsContentComponent) tabsContentList: QueryList<TabsContentComponent>;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.tabsContentList.forEach((tabInstance) => {
      var sanEle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(tabInstance.htmlContent)
      tabInstance.htmlContent = sanEle;
      return tabInstance
    })
  }
}
```

usage

```
  <il-tabs-group>
    <il-tabs-content label="hello-1">
      <h1>hello-1 content</h1>
    </il-tabs-content>
    <il-tabs-content label="hello-2">
      <h1>hello-2 content</h1>
    </il-tabs-content>
    <il-tabs-content label="hello-3">
      <h1>hello-3 content</h1>
      <h2>extra content</h2>
    </il-tabs-content>
  </il-tabs-group>
```

i defined two components 'il-tabs-content' and 'li-tabs-group'. with this now i can use my own custom tabs build over angular material tabing with dynamic tabs. Anyone with better approch are welcome to share their ideas. thanks

Answer (score 1):

the code you shared got the ng-content usage backwards... the `<custom-tabs-group>` will be at the parent level and `<ng-content>` at the child level.

I tried 2 approaches:

- **strategy #1**: pass the content to the custom child inside the `<mat-tab>`... this worked
- **strategy #2**: pass the content to the custom child where `<mat-tab>` is inside the child... this didn't work

you can [check the demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6a6oj?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: Actually my goal is to seperate mat-tab-group and mat-tab in two different components like in strategy #2. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

at first thanks for your code that points me to solution :) I think that I've upgraded it to fit your needs.

TabsContentComponent

```
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'il-tabs-content',
    templateUrl: './tab-content.component.html',
})
export class TabContentComponent {
    @Input() icon = '';
    @Input() label = '';
    @ViewChild('content') content!: TemplateRef<string>;
}
```

```
<ng-template #content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and in TabsGroupComponent:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ContentChildren, Input, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { TabContentComponent } from '@app/shared/components/tab-content/tab-content.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'il-tabs-group',
    templateUrl: './tabs-group.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tabs-group.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TabsGroupComponent {
    @Input() disableRipple = true;
    @Input() animationDuration = '0ms';
    @ContentChildren(TabContentComponent, {
        descendants: true,
    }) tabsContentList!: QueryList<TabContentComponent>;
}
```

```
<div class="tabs-group">
    <mat-tab-group [animationDuration]="animationDuration"
                   [disableRipple]="disableRipple">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabsContentList">
                <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                    <i class="icon {{tab.icon}}"></i>
                    <div class="label" translate>{{ tab.label }}</div>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tab.content"></ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

I have to be able to add custom icon so the code is more complicated, but at the end, it works fine without DOM Sanitization :)

Cheers